# Firebase Realtime Database is returning permission_denied for mobile but not desktop

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this realtime document structure:  `/calls/:calleeId/:callerId` and defined these rules

```
"calls": {
  "$calleeId": {
     ".read": "$calleeId === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$calleeId === auth.uid",
    
   "$callerId": {
      ".read": "$callerId === auth.uid",
      ".write": "$callerId === auth.uid",
    },
  }
}
```

These rules are working perfectly on desktop, but in mobile(web) im getting this error with the same users and context

[image: logs in safari mobile after lock screen for a while and unlock again]

this is my listener function

```js
      const callsRef = firebaseRealtimeDB.ref('calls')

      function initCallAnswerListener () {
        const {callerId, calleeId} = this.props
        if (callerId && calleeId) {
          this.currentCallRef = callsRef.child(calleeId).child(callerId)
          this.currentCallRef.on(
            'value',
            snapshot => {
              if (snapshot.val()) {
                this.call = snapshot.val()
                if (this.call.status === 'declinedByCallee') {
                  this.closeVideo('declinedByCallee')
                }
              }
            },
            errorObject => {
              console.log('Error reading call response')
              console.error(errorObject)
            },
          )
        }
      }
```

Steps to reproduce the bug (Safari/chrome  in iOS):

1. Realtime listener works normally
2. Lock the phone and wait until users is disconnected (i'm using '.info/connected to track it)
3. Unlock the phone. Now the calls listener deny the reads as the above image

PD: firestore listeners work after that

Comment: Please click the `edit` link under your question and add the minimal code for the mobile app that doesn't work, and the corresponding desktop app that does. Without seeing the minimal **code** that reproduces the problem, it'll be hard to say more than what the error message already does.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when i said mobile i meant web mobile so is technically the same as desktop

Comment: Interesting. So it sounds like on your mobile browser the session is not refreshed, or not refreshed in time. Do you have any more debug information? What phone/browser? Any logging you can show for when this happens?

Comment: Sure. I'm testing in Chrome and safari (iOS) . Just edited the post with the logs after lock the phone for a bunch of seconds. All the realtime listeners stop working for some reason